# select data from a table with a dropdown

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very big table where I add a column every month with new prices. Then, I have to perform some analysis with those values. I have already made it but with the name of the column in the formula. I want to know if I can point the formula to the drop-down so I just select the new period when it is available and get the results.

Here are some examples of the formulas I have been using:

`{=SUM(IF($B17=Matriz[money];Matriz[31-10-2013]*Matriz[country];0))}`

I would like to use something like

`{=SUM(IF($B17=Matriz[money];Matriz[*dropdow reference*]*Matriz[country];0))}`

pd: the `{ }` are for matrix calculations (when you use ctrl + shift + enter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use `INDEX`+`MATCH` instead `IDIRECT` (since `IDIRECT` is volatile function and your formula would be recalculated each time *any* cell changed):

`=SUM(IF($B17=Matriz[money];INDEX(Matriz[#Data];0;MATCH(A1;Matriz[#Headers];0))*Matriz[country];0))`

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.

alternatively you could use `SUMPRODUCT` - it doesn't require array entry:

`=SUMPRODUCT(($B17=Matriz[money])*INDEX(Matriz[#Data];0;MATCH(M2;Matriz[#Headers];0))*Matriz[country])`

I assumed that your dropdown value is in `A1` cell.

- this part `MATCH(A1;Matriz[#Headers];0)` finds value from `A1` cell
  in headers of your table
- this part `INDEX(Matriz[#Data];0;MATCH(A1;Matriz[#Headers];0))` gets
  corresponding column of data

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `indirect` function. With it, you can construct a string on the fly that contains your cell formula - then the indirect function will resolve the formula-string to its result.

A bit difficult to describe without a concrete example.

Have a look at the following resources:

[about.com](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/tipsandfaqs/ss/2013-08-02-excel-indirect-function.htm)

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm